# Create df or other array that counts entries from another df meeting specific criteria

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a current df containing entries like this:

```
     date     tags     ease
0   'date1'  'tag1'    1
1   'date1'  'tag1'    2
2   'date1'  'tag1'    1
3   'date1'  'tag2'    2
4   'date1'  'tag2'    2
5   'date2'  'tag1'    3
6   'date2'  'tag1'    1
7   'date2'  'tag2'    1
8   'date2'  'tag3'    1
```

I'd like to create a df (or some other type array if there is a better way to go about this-I'm green to Python and welcome suggestions) that counts the number of time a specific tag has a specific ease for each date in the df. For example, if I wanted to count the number of times each tag has an ease of 1 it would look something like this:

```
       date1    date2
tag1   2        1
tag2   1        2   
tag3   0        1
```

I can think of ways to do this using a loop, but my the final outputs are going to be about 700 x 800 and I need to make one for each "ease." I feel like there must be an efficient way to do this using indexing, hence why I looked first to pandas. As I said mentioned, I'm very new to Python if there are alternate approaches or packages I should consider using, I'm open for it.

Comment: Please post any attempt you've already made.

Comment: I haven't yet made an attempt with indexing. To be honest, I would love to receive some ideas of functions or other packages I should consider using and I can explore from there. I know SO isn't here to be a source of coders at my disposal, I just want to know what direction to go so I can self-learn from there. I can edit post to reflect that if necessary.

Comment: @jk3: unfortunately SO also isn't a place for recommendations or suggestions about libraries or packages (the answers tend to be too opinion-based.)

Comment: @DSM: my apologies...I'll refrain from such postings in the future. Any suggestions for where to find library or package recs in the future for specific projects? Thanks again for the guidance!

Comment: @jezrael and Psidom: Thanks for the recommendations. I'm not able to sit down and try out your suggestions right now but will provide feedback later tonight when I can try them out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = df[df['ease'] == 1]
df = pd.crosstab(df1['tags'], df1['date'])
print (df)
date    'date1'  'date2'
tags                    
'tag1'        2        1
'tag2'        0        1
'tag3'        0        1
```

Another solution where instead `crosstab` use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and for reshape [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df[df['ease'] == 1].groupby(["date", "tags"]).size().unstack(level=0, fill_value=0)
print (df)
date    'date1'  'date2'
tags                    
'tag1'        2        1
'tag2'        0        1
'tag3'        0        1
```

EDIT:

After testing solution I released is necessery add function [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), becasue if filter non `1` out values, it remove rows in final `DataFrame`.

```
print (df[df['ease'] == 1].groupby(["date", "tags"])
                          .size()
                          .unstack(level=0, fill_value=0)
                          .reindex(index=df.tags.unique(), columns=df.date.unique(), fill_value=0)
                          .sort_index()
                          .sort_index(axis=1))
```

And also second solution:

```
df1 = df[df['ease'] == 1]
df2 = pd.crosstab(df1['tags'], df1['date'])
        .reindex(index=df.tags.unique(), columns=df.date.unique(), fill_value=0)
        .sort_index()
        .sort_index(axis=1)
```

**Timings**:

(second solution of Psidom is wrong in general df, so I omit it from timings)

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 10000
dates = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=100)
tags = ['tag' + str(i) for i in range(100)]
ease = range(10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':np.random.choice(dates, N), 
                   'tags': np.random.choice(tags, N),
                   'ease': np.random.choice(ease, N)})
df = df.reindex_axis(['date','tags','ease'], axis=1)
#[10000 rows x 3 columns]
#print (df)
```

```
print (df.groupby(["date", "tags"]).agg({"ease": lambda x: (x == 1).sum()}).ease.unstack(level=0).fillna(0))

print (df[df['ease'] == 1].groupby(["date", "tags"]).size().unstack(level=0, fill_value=0).reindex(index=df.tags.unique(), columns=df.date.unique(), fill_value=0).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1))

def jez(df):
    df1 = df[df['ease'] == 1]
    return pd.crosstab(df1['tags'], df1['date']).reindex(index=df.tags.unique(), columns=df.date.unique(), fill_value=0).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)

print (jez(df))
```

---

```
#Psidom solution
In [56]: %timeit (df.groupby(["date", "tags"]).agg({"ease": lambda x: (x == 1).sum()}).ease.unstack(level=0).fillna(0))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.94 s per loop

In [57]: %timeit (df[df['ease'] == 1].groupby(["date", "tags"]).size().unstack(level=0, fill_value=0).reindex(index=df.tags.unique(), columns=df.date.unique(), fill_value=0).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1))
100 loops, best of 3: 5.74 ms per loop

In [58]: %timeit (jez(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 54.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Please check edited answer, I add reindex and sort_index function for same output and also add timings. In my opinion there are big differences, because faster is filtering first for smaller df, where apply generally slow `groupby` function as filtering each group by `agg`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option; Use `groupby.agg` to calculate the `count`, and then `unstack` the result to wide format:

```
(df.groupby(["date", "tags"])
   .agg({"ease": lambda x: (x == 1).sum()})
   .ease.unstack(level=0).fillna(0))
```

[image]

Or if you like to use `crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(df.tags, df.date, df.ease == 1, aggfunc="sum").fillna(0)

# date  'date1' 'date2'
# tags      
#'tag1'   2.0   1.0
#'tag2'   0.0   1.0
#'tag3'   0.0   1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using the pivot_table method on the DataFrame with a function of your own to do something that only counts if the condition you want is true. This should then also populate tags and dates where there is no data with a 0. Something like:

```
def calc(column):
    total = 0
    for e in column:
        if e == 1:
            total += 1
    return total

check_res = df.pivot_table(index='tags',columns='date', values='ease', aggfunc=calc, fill_value=0)
```